# Asp.net MVC 4.5.2 not redirecting after login with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, owin, openid-connect, identityserver4

I am integrating Identity Server 4 with Asp.net 4.5 MVC 4 web application. After hitting Authorize action redirecting to Identity server login page but after successful login, it is not coming again to client MVC application.

My client in identity server 4 is

```
new Client {  ClientId = "demo",
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "openid"},
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>{"http://localhost:51048/signin-oidc"},}
```

my startup contains

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000", //ID Server
                ClientId = "demo",
                ResponseType = "id_token code",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:51048/signin-oidc",
                Scope = "openid",               
            });
```

Comment: What do the logs say? also your RedirectUri configured for the client and in the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication's RedirectUri are not the same.

Comment: The ports of the redirect uri's are mismatching

Comment: Is the question now MVC4 or ASP.NET Core MVC related? The tags seem to  be confusing and from the first view on it unrelated to asp.net core

Comment: Redirect uri are same. i posted it wrong here. Client is on MVC 4.5.2 and using IdentityServer4 which is on asp.net core

Answer (score 1):

After successful login, by default the IdentityServer middleware tries to redirect to a consent page where to inform the user for the "allowed scopes". In this page are shown the claims that the client mvc site will receive access to: user identifier, user profile, email etc. If you didn't setup such, you may set: "RequireConsent = false" when you define your MVC client. In such scenario the IdentityServer will redirect back to "RedirectUris" without showing consent page.

Example:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientName = "mvc Client",
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
            },
            RequireConsent = false
        }
    };
}
```

The other thing that I've noticed in the IdentityServer4 demos and quick starts is that you need the following NuGet packages: For client website: IdentityModel, Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

For IdentityServer Authentication app: IdentityServer4, IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation, IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity, Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

Answer (score 0):

Add `AuthenticationScheme` and `SigninScheme` to the `UseOpenIdConnectAuthorization` options:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
    SignInScheme = "Cookies"
    // other options omitted...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case the cause of this error was adding custom Authorize attributes and **opening a session after user got authorized** to save user info.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class SecureController
```

so the solution for me was **not to open a session** on AuthorizeCore function but adding the required data in claims as following

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(

            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = Settings.Default.AuthenticationOptionsClientId,
                ClientSecret = Settings.Default.AuthenticationOptionsClientSecret,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                AuthenticationType = Settings.Default.AuthenticationOptionsAuthenticationType,
                Authority = Settings.Default.AuthenticationOptionsAuthority,
                RedirectUri = Settings.Default.AuthenticationOptionsRedirectUri,
                ResponseType = Settings.Default.AuthenticationOptionsResponseType,
                UseTokenLifetime = Settings.Default.AuthenticationOptionsUseTokenLifetime,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,


                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);

                        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserData", "User Data Content"));

                        context.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            claimsIdentity,
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                    }
                }
            });
```